# Load Variable Definition from Perl Script

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script and I need to do the following:

1. There is a file, call it `machine_specs`
2. The entire file consists of a single Perl hash definition, with associated key, value pairs like `('word_length' => 64)` and `('os_ver' => 'RHEL Server release 5.8')`
3. I want to load this variable into my script so that I can access the fields naturally.

I know I could just `grep FIELD machine_specs` and parse the output to get the info, and maybe that is what I should do. But now I just want to know how to load in a variable definition. I am not sure `use` is appropriate, since these files are not really modules; they're just text with a single dictionary.

Without loss of generality, we can pretend the entire file is:  `%report = ('bits' => 64, 'os_ver' => 'RHEL Server release 5.8', 'os_arch' => 'x86_64');`

Comment: Is the file compilable Perl code? Run `perl -c /path/to/file` to see.

Comment: Returned `syntax OK`, so I think that is a yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file contains valid perl, you can use [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) to pull the variable into your script.

`machine_specs` content:

```
%report = (
    'bits'    => 64,
    'os_ver'  => "RHEL Server release 5.8",
    'os_arch' => "x86_64",
)
```

Example script content:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our %report;
require "machine_specs";

print "Got $report{bits} bits!\n"; # Got 64 bits!
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need to do ?

```
my %report;
eval <DATA>;
print Dumper(\%report);

__DATA__
%report = ('bits' => 64, 'os_ver' => 'RHEL Server release 5.8', 'os_arch' => 'x86_64');
```